# Assign Rank/Index to Records in Sorted MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access query which I'm sorting using data which cannot be output for confidentiality reasons, however, I need to include a rank or index in the output such that the sort order can be maintained.

Currently, my approach is loosely as follows:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim dst As DAO.Recordset
Dim idx As Long

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5 FROM MyTable ORDER BY Field6")
Set dst = cdb.OpenRecordset("MyOutputTable")
idx = 1

If Not rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        dst.AddNew
        dst!Field1 = rst!Field1
        dst!Field2 = rst!Field2
        dst!Field3 = rst!Field3
        dst!Field4 = rst!Field4
        dst!Field5 = rst!Field5
        dst!Rank = idx
        dst.Update
        idx = 1 + idx
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
dst.Close
rst.Close

Set dst = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

However:

- This necessitates creating an output table with a pre-existing 'Rank' field to house the results.
- Populating the value of every individual field in the output table within the `Do` loop is incredibly tedious... there must be a better way!

Therefore, my question is whether this result can be obtained using only a query, and without the mundane VBA?

Many thanks in advance for your time & help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a query to achieve this result, by using a subquery:

```sql
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, 
(
SELECT Count(s.Field6)
FROM MyTable s
WHERE s.Field6 <= t.Field6
) As Rank
FROM MyTable t
ORDER BY Field6
```

Note that this will have a substantial impact on performance, as the subquery needs to be reran for every row.

Also note that for rows with an equal value for Field6, their rank will be equal, in contrast to your VBA code where their rank is not equal.

Comment: Many thanks Erik! Are `MyTable s` and `MyTable t` shorthand for `MyTable AS s` and `MyTable AS t`? Also, if I were to opt for a compromise between the VBA solution and your solution by processing the ordered RecordSet, is there a better way to assign the field values? (Or should this be posted as a separate question?)

Comment: It indeed is a shorthand, omitting the `As`. I don't know why you would want to compromise. If you have an unique identifier, I can adjust the query to return identical output as your VBA solution. If it's because you want to move the rows over to another table, an append query can do that.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Regarding the compromise, I was considering that processing the recordset would be much more efficient than using the subquery, but was looking for a cleaner solution than a list of `dst!Field1 = rst!Field1`...

Comment: VBA solutions are rarely more efficient than pure SQL solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my *RowCounter* function. See in-line comments for typical usage:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example! This is a good demonstration of using a Collection and Static variables and so helps a lot.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, presumably this example relies on the `ORDER BY` instruction being executed prior to the `RowCounter` function?

Comment: No, only a (concatenated) unique key is needed. Sorting is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Learning from @Gustav's solution, I realised that since I'm not actually counting records aggregated by a key, but rather only assigning a rank or index to a sorted set, I could use the following simple VBA code:

```
Function RowRank(Optional varTmp, Optional bolRst As Boolean) As Long
    Static lngRow As Long
    If bolRst Then lngRow = 0 Else lngRow = 1 + lngRow
    RowRank = lngRow
End Function
```

Evaluated using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    t.*, RowRank([Field6]) AS Rank
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Field6) AS t
WHERE 
    RowRank("",True) = 0
```

Here, the `RowRank` function is initialised in the `WHERE` clause, and the first argument supplied to the `RowRank` function in the `SELECT` statement is merely a dummy argument in order to force the `RowRank` function to be evaluated for every record in the table `t`.